# Django form not appearing in Template

Tags: python, django

I've got a form that I display on the same page as a search results page.

The form class is as follows:

```
class MailForm(forms.Form):
    toEmail = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area',
                                                        'placeholder': 'Enter the mail ID to whom you want to send this'}))
    fromName = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area',
                                                         'placeholder': 'Enter your name'}))
    message = forms.Textarea()
```

I'm rendering it into a Bootstrap modal as follows:

```
{% if form.errors %}
    <p>Please correct the {{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.</p>
{% endif %}
<form action="" method="post">
{{ form.as_table }}
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

views.py

```
def search_page_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        forms = MailForm(request.POST)
        if forms.is_valid():
            cd = forms.cleaned_data
            send_mail(
                cd['toEmail'],
                cd['fromName'],
                cd['message'],
                cd.get('email', 'noreply@shp.com'),
                ['toEmail']
            )
    else:
        forms = MailForm()
    return render_to_response('templates/search.html', {'form': forms})
```

I think the problem is that I'm rendering search results on the same page too which is as follows:

```
def search_page(request):
    if 'query' in request.GET and request.GET['query']:
        city = request.GET['city']
        q = request.GET['query']
        ct = Classified.objects.filter(name__icontains=q).filter(address__city__name__exact=city).filter(active__exact='yes')
        paginate = Paginator(ct, 10)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            ct = paginate.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            ct = paginate.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            ct = paginate.page(paginate.num_pages)
        return render(request, 'templates/search.html', {'ct': ct, 'query': q, 'city': city, })
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Please submit a search term.')
```

Is there an error that prevents the form from being displayed in the modal?

Comment: Please add the outputted html.

Comment: We need more details.  you have two separate views. How are they both being called? Are you using an ajax request? Show us your urls. what does the template look like? Not just the modal snippet.